# How do I set up "blog" posts to a page other than the main/home page?

Tags: blog-page

Someone set me up with some custom work on top od another them and now I want to add a "what's new"/"blog"/"latest news" type page that is accessible from the main menu and is NOT the home page.

How can I do that?  It is not obvious to me how that is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin area,

Go to **Settings » Reading**, Choose '**A Static Page**' from the first set of options & select the two pages you would like to use as the front-page & blog/news page.

Hope this helps,
G

Comment: Great - thanks.  I found that.  Now I just have to mangle the css so it looks ok in my template.

Comment: Handy tip if you don't know it - if you create a template called 'front-page.php' this will automatically be used on the landing page. Good luck with the CSS!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by category. Add the "blog" category to all of your blog posts, and then set up your menu to add a "Blog" link, type - "category", and enter "blog" for the category. Then, whenever somebody clicks the blog link it will go to the /blog category.